# A characterisation of faces of rational polyhedral cones

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, convex-geometry, semigroups-and-monoids, toric-varieties, cones

This is about a (seemingly) basic lemma about rational polyhedral cones that is sometimes used when working with toric varieties and is usually "left to the reader". Unfortunately, I could neither prove it myself nor find a complete proof in the literature. So, I am looking for either a proof or a proper reference.

> **Lemma.** Let $V$ be an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of finite dimension, and let $N$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-structure on $V$ (i.e., a free abelian group with $N\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}=V$). Let $\sigma$ and $\tau$ be $N$-rational polyhedral cones in $V$, and suppose that $\tau$ is a *subset* of $\sigma$. Then, the following statements are equivalent:
>
> (i) $\tau$ is a face of $\sigma$;
>
> (ii) If $x,y\in\sigma$ with $x+y\in\tau$, then $x,y\in\tau$;
>
> (iii) If $x,y\in\sigma\cap N$ with $x+y\in\tau$, then $x,y\in\tau$.

Showing that (i) and (ii) are equivalent and imply (iii) is clear. My problem is to show that (iii) implies (i) or (ii), i.e., that it suffices to consider only rational points.

**Note 1.** Trying to show (iii)$\Rightarrow$(i) analogously to (ii)$\Rightarrow$(i) leads to the question whether $(\sigma-\tau)\cap N=(\sigma\cap N)-(\tau\cap N)$, which has a negative answer in general.

**Note 2.** Condition (iii) is sometimes expressed by saying that the monoid $\tau\cap N$ is a face of the monoid $\sigma\cap N$, and similarly for (ii).

Comment: I'd think that (iii) implies (ii) as you can approximate $x\in\sigma$ by $x'\in\sigma\cap N$ arbitrarily well.

Comment: Dear @Dima: Yes, that's why I think the claim is true. Can you provide details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prove that (iii) implies (i), assume w.l.o.g. that $\tau\neq\sigma$. We first need to show that $\tau\subset \partial \sigma$.  If this is not the case then either there exists a hyperplane $H$ containing $\tau$ such that $H$ is not a supporting hyperplane for $\sigma$, or $\tau$ is full-dimensional. If $H$ exists then there are $x,y\in\sigma$ on different sides of $H$, which may be chosen in $N$ as $\sigma$ is rational, so that $x+y\in\tau$, contadicting (iii).

If $H$ does not exist, then $\dim \tau=\dim\sigma$, and there exists $x\in\sigma\setminus\tau$ ($x$ may be chosen to be a generator for an extreme ray of $\sigma$) and $y\in\tau\setminus\partial\tau$ (again, it's possible to choose  $x,y\in N$) so that $x+y\in\tau$, again contradicting (iii).

Thus $\tau\subset \partial \sigma$. Let $\sigma'$ be the minimal face of $\sigma$ containing $\tau$. Note that $\sigma'$ is a rational polyhedral cone, and we are basically in the situation as above, with $\sigma$ replaced by $\sigma'$, except that we don't have any more dimensions to spare, and so either $\tau=\sigma'$, as required, or we contradict (iii) as above.

Comment: Dear @Dima, in the case where $H$ does not exist, why can you choose $y$ in $N$?

Comment: if $H$ does not exist, then there is a ray of $\sigma$ which is not in $\tau$, and this ray is rational, so its generator $y$  is in $N$.

Comment: Yes, this yields an element in $\sigma\cap N\setminus\tau$, called $x$ in your answer. But we also need an element of $\tau\cap N$, called $y$ in your answer, with $x+y\in\tau$.

Comment: If there is no $H$ then $\tau$ is full-dimensional; pick any rational $x$ in the interior of $\tau$. Let $y_0\not\in\tau$ be a rational generator of a ray of $\sigma$. Then there exists a positive integer $m$ so that $y:=\frac{1}{m}y_0$ satisfies $x+y\in\tau$. (You can check this in the plane generated by $x$ and $y_0$).

Comment: For a reference, see Mustata's lectures on toric varieties, Lecture 2, Proposition 10.  (The definition of "face of a semigroup" is in Lecture 1.)  Here is the link: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mmustata/toric_var.html

Comment: @Dave: I don't see the relevance of Prop. 10 to my question. Prop. 8 claims that (i)-(iii) are equivalent, but the point in question here is not explained. May I ask you to elaborate?

Comment: @Dima: Sorry for all the questions, but there is a last point that is unclear to me. In the case where $H$ exists, I know how to choose rational $x$ and $y$ on both sides of $H$ such that $x+y$ lies in $H$. How do you get them such that $x+y$ lies in $\tau$?

Comment: $H$ is affine span of rational vectors: generators of $\tau$, and, maybe, some generators of $\sigma$, if needed. Thus the normal vector $h$ to $H$ is rational. Take a non-zero  $u\in\tau\cap N$, then there exists smalll positive rational $q$ so that $x=u+qh\in\sigma\$.  Similarly, $y=u-qh\in\sigma\cap N$. And so $x+y=2u\in\tau$.

Comment: ...then there exists smalll positive rational $q$ so that $x=u+qh\in\sigma\cap N$.  Similarly, $y=u-qh\in\sigma\cap N$. And so $x+y=2u\in\tau\cap N$.

Comment: if you prefer you may think about the cones $\tau^+$, resp. $\tau^-$, rational cones spanned by the generators of $\tau$, and the generators of $\sigma$ on the "+" side of $H$, resp. "-" side of $H$. Then $x$ and $y$ may be chosen in $\tau^+$, resp. $\tau^-$.

Comment: Dear @Dima, thanks a lot! Now everything is clear.